# Anonymous deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Who deleted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619042/android-storing-several-mb-of-app-data-safely-security-error-free-and-consider/5619384#5619384)? (Sorry, only visible to 10K)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did.  I initially misinterpreted the flag as notifying the user badly formatted their answer.  Got another flag pointing out that it was a copy paste of another answer in the same question.

It was the first answer from an unregistered account.  Was it your bot?

Comment: Considering he's the one who alerted you, I think not. :)

Comment: @Will :) I was the one that flagged the question as a copy. I am interested just because the deletion is not "signed", and I am curious about why.

Comment: That's what a sock would say @mmy

Comment: No true sockpuppet would say that, @random!

Comment: Hey! May be I'm a sock, but never a puppet!

Comment: brb, deleting more bots

Answer (score 4):

Whoever destroyed the user. The most important part of the screenshot is the part that isn't there.

Comment: The part that isn't there only mentions the poster's name. Is there a way to know the deleter's name not being a mod?

Comment: @Wether: Since the answer was posted less than a day ago and the account is no longer active, it's a pretty safe bet that a moderator destroyed it. But even mods can't access account pages for deleted accounts, so you can't tell more than that unless the perp confesses (which he did).

Comment: Hmm, maybe the message here should show "deleted by account destroying" or something similar.